# How can I fix Mouse/Keyboard input lag when sound/video is being played?

Tags: windows-10, audio, mouse, windows-update, lag

I have just updated windows 10 and after restarting the computer, an old issue that has mysteriously fixed itself before reappeared.

My mouse/keyboard input is lagging whenever I open or focus on a program window that plays sound (or a video with sound). Even windows notification noises when a USB is inserted cause that lag.

Clarifications :

- I can play Gifs normally.
- Muting all sound coming from speakers doesn't help.
- I have updated all drivers
- The issue only happens on windows (I USB-booted linux and played music and videos without any problem)

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZW7xrF8eywQZc4yoeFV0WW5DvmjRyQ-F/view?usp=sharing)'s a preview, notice how the mouse only lags when I focus on chrome.

Comment: Your hardware would probably help.  This problem is too generic without more details.

Comment: It's obviously a windows/software problem, not a hardware one (it reappeared after update, and everything works on linux). I don't think it's the drivers since both mouse and keyboard are lagging. P.S. what's your Windows version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by manually downloading and updating all of my sound drivers (not using the the windows search automatically for driver updates option).